# Swiping in order to call another Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, swipe

I want to make something like transitions between ViewControllers in iOS 7 but in Android, is it possible?

Explanation: please look at image below, I have main Activity which has ViewPager inside, so we can swipe between Fragments. I want to call another Activity (or Fragment) from each Fragment (blue on image) swiping to bottom or to top but this action should be done smoothly like in ViewPager.

[image: img]

Comment: You definitely cannot do it via activities. There's an open source vertical `ViewPager` floating about you are welcome to experiment with, though whether it will work on conjunction with a regular `ViewPager`, I cannot say. I am also somewhat skeptical that users will find your navigation to be especially intuitive.

Comment: I also claim that this is not intuitive but it is designer's+customer's will...

Comment: [Android L Compatibility](http://developer.android.com/preview/material/compatibility.html): `The following new APIs are only available in the Android L Developer Preview: Activity transitions (...)` We have to wait :)

Comment: That's not going to give you the same experience as you get with a `ViewPager`. To get an activity transition, you have to call `startActivity()`. If you allow the user to swipe, they will not move anything, then after some swipe distance is reached, you call `startActivity()` and the transition occurs. Contrast that with `ViewPager`, where the animation is driven incrementally by the swipe itself, following the finger.

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept swipe up and down gestures and set items in viewpager accordingly. Please read [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) on how to intercept swipes in various directions.